# Ошибка ноды (node:22205) [DEP0025] DeprecationWarning: sys is deprecated. Use util instead

Tags: javascript, node.js

Поскольку совсем не владею JS, не знаю как правильно и куда прописать в теле скрипта путь к файлу, чтобы заработало.
Скрипт отсюда: https://github.com/jeffslofish/swc-hh-convert/blob/master/swcWatch.js

Ноду поставил, и если я правильно понял нода запускается командой `node swcWatch.js path-to-swc-hh-files > out.txt` , где вместо `path-to-swc-hh-files` подставляется путь к файлу как первый аргумент: `node swcWatch.js "/home/user/путь" > out.txt`
или же мне нужно прописать в теле путь к текстовому файлу (hand history directory) в самом теле скрипта , откуда этот конвертер будет брать историю покерных рук и конвертировать его в нужный формат? Я выделил ** 
где об этом написано

```
if (!hhDir) {
    sys.puts("You must provide the swc hand history directory as the first argument.");
    process.exit(1);
}
```

При запуске `node swcWatch.js "/home/user/путь" > out.txt`
выдает: `(node:22205) [DEP0025] DeprecationWarning: sys is deprecated. Use util instead.`
Нода у меня последних версий, а скрипту уже 5 лет, как заменить и что на что в теле скрипта, чтобы заработало? (Или какой старой версии поставить ноду, чтобы не ругалось?)

Спасибо

```
/**
* This script watches the directory specified by the first argument to the script
* and will take Seals With Clubs hand histories and convert them to Full Tilt 
* hand histories.
*/
var sys = require("sys");  
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var Tail = require('tail').Tail;
var convert = require('./swcConvert.js');
var hhDir = process.argv[2]; 

if (/^win/.test(process.platform)) {
    var separator = "\\"
} else {
    var separator = "/"
}

if (!hhDir) {
    sys.puts(**"You must provide the swc hand history directory as the first argument."**);
    process.exit(1);
}

var tail;

/**
* Tail all existing files in hh directory
*/
var existingFiles = fs.readdirSync(hhDir);
for (var i = 0; i < existingFiles.length; i++) {
    tail = new Tail(hhDir + separator + existingFiles[i]);
    tail.on("line", function(data) {
        bufferTillRake(data);
    });
}


/**
* Tail files that are added to hh directory
*/
fs.watch(hhDir, function(event, filename) { 
    if (filename && event == 'rename') {
        tail = new Tail(hhDir + separator + filename);
        tail.on("line", function(data) {
            bufferTillRake(data);
        });
    }
});


/**
* Buffers all lines of data sent to this function until it sees 'Rake (',
* which signifies the end of the hand. Once the whole hand has been buffers
* it is sent along to another function for processing.
*/
var hand = "";
function bufferTillRake(data) {
    hand += "\n" + data;
    if (data.substr(0,6) == "Rake (") {
        hand += "\n\n";
        var convertedHand = convert.convert(hand, 1);
        console.log(convertedHand);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Замените `sys.puts` на `console.log`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удалите

```
var sys = require("sys");
```

и замените **sys.puts** на **console.log** , так как

```
> let sys=require('sys')
undefined
> (node:18849) [DEP0025] DeprecationWarning: sys is deprecated. Use util instead.
> let util=require('util')
undefined
> util.puts('test')
test
undefined
> (node:18849) [DEP0027] DeprecationWarning: util.puts is deprecated. Use console.log instead.
```

т.е. модуль sys уже устарел и вместо него советуют использовать util, в котором метод util.puts тоже устарел и советует использовать console.log =)

Comment: ошибка пропала, да. Добиться работы конвертера правда пока не удалось,  возможно правда из-за нового формата history файла новой версии покера, а конвертер старой.